# zsh prompt arch-installation shell seems to break with unknown commands

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, system-installation, root

[image: screenshot]

Apologies in advance if I am asking an unimportant question, but I can't find any information about this anywhere and it's making me crazy. See image above.

This is taking place in the arch installation shell, and I have been able to reproduce this both in virtualbox and on bare metal booted from a usb. When one first boots from the arch iso, one is presented with a root shell with a zsh prompt that looks like `root@archiso ~ #` if one enters recognized commands, the prompt stays the same, but if one enters unrecognized commands, then the user field of the zsh prompt changes from `root` to `1 root` on the first command, and then from subsequent commands onwards the prompt becomes `127 root@archiso ~ #`

To be clear, the command line still functions, and it's possible to proceed with the installation as usual, but the root prompt being changed in this way is confusing and a little worrying without knowing what might cause this.

I am unfamiliar with zsh so maybe this is a zsh quirk and not an arch linux thing, but I don't know enough to understand what could be causing the username to display some increment. The fact that it stops at 127 seems like a clue since 127 would be the highest value of 7 bits. Is this a bug? Is this somehow exploitable? Has anyone else ever noticed this? Can anyone explain why this might be happening? Thanks for your help!

My `PS1` is:

```
# echo "$PS1"
%B%F{red}%(?..%? )%f%b%B%F{red}%n%f%b@%m %B%40<…<%~%<< %b%#
```

Comment: Looks like it is simply including the exit status of the last command in the prompt. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `echo "$PS1"` so we can see what the default prompt is. But you can confirm by simply running `echo $?` after every command and you'll see it's the same number.

Comment: Thanks terdon, you're right! `echo $?` matches the number. But why would the exit status of the previous command be bleeding into the prompt? I added the $PS1 variable

Answer (score 1):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466245/customize-zshs-prompt-when-displaying-previous-command-exit-code).

which explains that

> "`Zsh` includes the ability to display the return `code/exit` code of
> the previous command in the prompt by using the `%?` escape sequence."
> The `%?` escape sequence is included in the `zsh` prompt so I guess
> this is expected behavior based on a choice that the arch `devs` made
> when configuring the `zsh` prompt for the installation shell.

So that answers the question I guess. Thanks!